# How to count number of rotations using Hall sensor in Arduino?

Tags: c, arduino, embedded, microcontroller, sensors

I want to count the number of rotations using a Hall sensor when a button is pressed. So for counting I have written this code:

```cpp
const int hallPin = D3;
boolean lastRevolutionPin = LOW;
boolean currentRevolutionPin = LOW;
unsigned long Count = 0;
    
void setup() {
  pinMode (hallPin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
    
void loop() {
  currentRevolutionPin = check(lastRevolutionPin, hallPin);
  if (lastRevolutionPin == HIGH && currentRevolutionPin == LOW) {
    Count++;
    Serial.println(Count)
  }
  lastRevolutionPin = currentRevolutionPin;
}
    
boolean check(boolean last, int pin) {
  boolean current = digitalRead(pin);
  if (last != current) {
    delay(5);
    current = digitalRead(pin);
  }
  return current;
}
```

Now this code is working but when I try to use it as a function that will start counting and return feedback after a number of turns, the function gets into an infinite loop and I get a soft WTD reset.

So please show me how to create a function that counts the number of revolutions and after a specific rotation returns a value that I can then perform another operation on after that fixed number of rotations.

Here is the code where I have tried make a function to count, but it gets into an infinite loop and causes a watchdog reset.

```cpp
const int hallPin = D3;
boolean lastRevolutionPin = LOW;
boolean currentRevolutionPin = LOW;
unsigned long Count = 0;
    
void setup() {
  pinMode (hallPin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
    
void loop() {
  Serial.println(pleasecountaccurate());
  Count = 0;
}
    
int pleasecountaccurate() {
  while (Count < 20) { // I want to return only when it completed 20 rotations 
    currentRevolutionPin = check(lastRevolutionPin, hallPin);
    if (lastRevolutionPin == HIGH && currentRevolutionPin == LOW) {
      Count++;
    }
    lastRevolutionPin = currentRevolutionPin;
  }
  return Count;
}
    
boolean check(boolean last, int pin) {
  boolean current = digitalRead(pin);
  if (last != current) {
    delay(5);
    current = digitalRead(pin);
  }
  return current;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid having any blocking code while coding for small embedded devices.  Doing so will create all kinds of issues, including lack of responsiveness, inability to do simple things like flashing an LED, and issues with the watchdog.

The watchdog is reset every time you exit of loop(), so if you have the watchdog on, you must avoid blocking at all times.

If you do not block, you should not miss any pulses from the hall sensor.

Have you tried this?

```
constexpr int hallPin = D3;       // using constexpr here saves 2 bytes of RAM.

unsigned char turnsCount = 0;
bool lastHallState = false;

// note that variables are passed by reference, making this function
// available for any number of hall sensors.
bool CheckTurnsCount(int pin, bool& lastState, unsigned char& count, unsigned char maxCount)
{
    bool curState = digitalRead(pin); 

    count += (lastState && !curState);  // tests and comparisons return either 0 or 1
    lastState = curState;

    if (count < maxCount)
        return false;

    count = 0;
    return true;
}

void setup() 
{
    pinMode (hallPin, INPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    lastHallState = digitalRead(hallPin);
}

void loop()
{
    if (CheckTurnsCount(hallPin, lastHallState, turnsCount, 20))
        Serial.println("tick");

    // here you should still have plenty of cpu time for other controls ;)
}
```